# My Android App Crashed at the time of recieve push notification from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, push

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-MyFirebaseMessagingService
                                                                           Process: com.example.admin.myfolks, PID: 20803
                                                                           java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.zzd(android.content.Intent)"
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Comment: Add the code of your MessagingService class

Comment: bro i can't understand. which class ?? i added all the service

Comment: check this page. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive. If you follow the instruction correctly, it should be working.